# Font issues with Crosscompiled OpenJDK on PPC32

Tags: fonts, x11, java, xorg

I am upgrading from OpenJDK-6 to OpenJDK-8 on an embedded platform and have problems with the fonts. We're using the DejaVu fonts. I have created a suitable fontconfig.properties file in the jre/lib directory, and when I list the fonts with java i get the list as follows:

```
DejaVu Sans
DejaVu Sans Condensed
DejaVu Sans Light
DejaVu Sans Mono
DejaVu Serif
DejaVu Serif Condensed
Dialog
DialogInput
Monospaced
SansSerif
Serif
```

The application in question is an AWT application - because it is running under PPC32 using the Zero JVM (haven't installed JamVM yet), but shows artefacts when rendering the fonts on the screen.

[image: Black on gray - yellow around the letters]

[image: White On black - w/ blue in the box of the letter]

The issue looks like it is changing the background as well...
The embedded system is running x11 7.7, with freetype, fontconfig, dejavu fonts.

How can I get the fonts to render correctly inside Java? I tried XFD, and that doesn't show any artefacts at all...

fontconfig.properties:

```
#

# Version

version=1

# Component Font Mappings

serif.plain.latin-1=DejaVu Serif
serif.bold.latin-1=DejaVu Serif Bold
serif.italic.latin-1=DejaVu Serif Oblique
serif.bolditalic.latin-1=DejaVu Serif Bold Oblique
sansserif.plain.latin-1=DejaVu Sans
sansserif.bold.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Bold
sansserif.italic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Oblique
sansserif.bolditalic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique
monospaced.plain.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono
monospaced.bold.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Bold
monospaced.italic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique
monospaced.bolditalic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Bold Oblique
dialog.plain.latin-1=DejaVu Sans
dialog.bold.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Bold
dialog.italic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Oblique
dialog.bolditalic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique
dialoginput.plain.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono
dialoginput.bold.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Bold
dialoginput.italic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique
dialoginput.bolditalic.latin-1=DejaVu Sans Mono Bold Oblique

#
# Search Sequences

sequence.allfonts=latin-1

# Font File Names

filename.DejaVu_Sans=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Bold=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSans-    Oblique.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Bold_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSans-    BoldOblique.ttf

filename.DejaVu_Sans_Mono=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Mono_Bold=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-    Bold.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Mono_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Sans_Mono_Bold_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf

filename.DejaVu_Serif=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSerif.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Serif_Bold=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Serif_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSerif-    Oblique.ttf
filename.DejaVu_Serif_Bold_Oblique=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/DejaVuSerif-    BoldOblique.ttf


# AWT X11 font paths
awtfontpath.latin-1=/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/
```

Font directories:

```
ls /usr/share/fonts/ -lR
/usr/share/fonts/:
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            62 Oct 30 21:59 X11
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.scale

/usr/share/fonts/X11:
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           741 Oct 30 21:50 TTF
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             2 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.scale

/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF:
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        672300 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        611212 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        345208 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        611556 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        720012 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSans.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        631992 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        580168 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        576004 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        643852 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        313856 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        235848 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        241972 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        333636 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSansMono.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        341072 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        332036 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        338776 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        363200 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerif.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        316440 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        331128 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        338140 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        330012 Oct 30 21:50 DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         43905 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         43905 Oct 30 21:59 fonts.scale
```

XLSFONTS:

```
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--0-0-75-75-c-0-iso8859-1
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-100-100-100-c-60-iso8859-1
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
6x13
cursor
fixed
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but haven't been able to find what...